# Node.js Multer Filename

Tags: node.js, express, filenames, multer

I want to customizes the filename of my app by the value of an input instead of the fieldname. 
In the other words, I want to change the *file.filename* by one thing like *req.body.my_field* were my_field is the name of an input. 
Finally, I want something like this:

```
"filename": "value_of_my_field-1530606094020.jpg",  
"path": "uploads\\value_of_my_field-1530606094020.jpg",
```

Noticed that the value of my_field appear on my console.
I need some help to do this.
 Here's my code:

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
const path = require('path')

// Init app
var app = express()
const port= 3000

// Set storage engine
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './uploads/',
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() +     path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

// Init upload
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits:{fileSize:1000000},
});


app.post('/upload', upload.single('myImage'), function (req, res, next) {
    if(req.file == undefined){
        res.json({'Error': 'No File Selected!'});
    } else {
        res.json(req.file);
        console.log(req.body.my_field);
    }
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log('server started on port '+ port));
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your issue is, as it seems like your code is currently doing what you want it to do (save the file with a timestamp). If you want to get rid of the logging of `req.body.my_field` remove the line `console.log(req.body.my_field);`

Comment: This line verify just the content of the req.body.my_field. I want just this value on my filename

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the `req` object in the filename function. So you can do something like this -

```
// Set storage engine
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './uploads/',
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, req.body.my_field + '-' + Date.now() +     path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried to do this but the result is undefined. "filename": "undefined-1530620975355.jpg",
    "path": "uploads\\undefined-1530620975355.jpg",

Comment: can you do `console.log(req.body)` and see what you're getting?

Comment: when I put this inside the app.post I get this result on my console {my_field: 'value_of_field'}. But when I put this inside the filename function I got this {}